# Merging multiple tex files of different document class

Tags: pdftex

I have two tex files one for the main manuscript and the other for the supporting infomation. The definition of the documentclass is different for both tex files. Like for the main manuscript I defined as manuscript = article while for the supporting information I defined as manuscript = suppinfo. Now I want to compile both tex files together and generate a single pdf file. I tried to make a separate tex file and there I put `\include{Foo1/foo1}` and `\include{Foo2\foo2}` but it is not working. I know this works when you have one type of documentclass but in my case as I said I have two documentclass (manuscript = article and manuscript=suppinfo). Can anyone give me any idea how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Just merge the two pdfs outside LaTeX.

Comment: Yes I did this. But would like to know if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: You can only have one documentclass but it is usually not hard to edit the document so that they use the same class.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Out of curiousity I tried to solve this with `\def\documentclass{}`. `\show` reveals that I have succesfully redefined it, but the log file still says that I can only use `\documentclass` in the preamble. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: @jaspast hard to guess what you did, but after the first use of `\documentclass` it redefines itself to be an error, so it depends on the timing, where you tried the redefinition.